# Django form fields to HTML

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm crating fields in a for loop and storing them in a list in a Django form.
When trying to place the fields in the HTML file, it appears to be printing the object.

Something like this: <django.forms.fields.IntegerField object at ...>

My HTML looks like this:

```
{% for i in form.list %}
    {{i}}
{% endfor %}
```

This is how I create the list:

```
l1 = [] #List that contains names 
l2 = [] #List that contains other names 
result = {} 
for i in l1: 
   for j in l2: 
      v_name = i + '_' + j 
          result[v_name] = forms.IntegerField()
```

How can I convert that string to an actual input?

Comment: What is form.list?

Comment: It's a python list that contains all the Integer Fields I created.

Comment: You have access to your field already, no need to create a new list, pass the form instance in the context and access it in your template then take care of the display

Comment: I need to create a list because I'm creating fields with dynamic variable names, as I need close to 200 inputs. I cannot create them manually.

Comment: Can you show how you create your fields? You can add fields to the `self.fields` dictionary to dynamically add fields

Comment: @Alfonso please add it to the question

Comment: What ever you are doing is wrong. But to help with your question. You are adding an object of IntegerField which is why it is printing the object.
Now each IntegerField has a 'widget' attribute, try printing that instead.
If that doesn't work either, since widget itself is an object.Each widget has a template, so include the template in the html e.g i.widget.template_name. This will just put an html number input field, if thats what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add fields to the `self.fields` dictionary in `Form.__init__` to dynamically add fields to a form.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in l1: 
            for j in l2: 
                v_name = i + '_' + j 
                self.fields[v_name] = forms.IntegerField()
```

This can be used like a regular form, or iterated over

```
{{ form }}

{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```